# Tkinter GUI - Can't pass argument to script

Tags: python, shell, tkinter

I've made a GUI with Tkinter and i linked a script to a button. I've also created a browse file option in my GUI and when i select a file i store it's path into a variable named "file". What i'm trying to do is click the button and run the script using the path i stored into the variable "file", but i get a 'no such file or directory error'. The solution must be pretty obvious but i just can't figure it out. Here's my GUI code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess

window = Tk()

#modify window 
window.title("Random Title")
window.geometry("600x400")

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

#Creating tabs
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

#Modifying tabs
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Issue')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Verify')

file = ""

var = StringVar()
var.set("")
w = Entry(tab2,textvariable=var)
w.grid(column=1,row=0)

#Creating button & actions
def issue():
    subprocess.call('./issue_script.sh', shell=True)
    messagebox.showinfo('Issue Certificate', 'Certificate issued successfully!')
btn = Button(tab1, text="Issue Certificate", command=issue) 
btn.grid(column=1, row=5)

def browse():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("all files","*.*"),("Text files","*.txt"))) 
    var.set(file)
    print(file)

btn2 = Button(tab2, text="Browse", command=browse) 
btn2.grid(column=3, row=0)

def verify():

    subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', file], shell=True)

btn = Button(tab2, text="Verify Certificate", command=verify) 
btn.grid(column=1, row=5)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

#event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I've also added a `print(file)` command so that i see what is stored in the variable and i get the correct result(the path i selected). Maybe the error is in the line i call the script `subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', file], shell=True)` or in the script itself. Here's the script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Verifying certificate..."

cd

python3 cert-issuer/cert-verifier/cert_verifier/verifier.py $1
```

Comment: The path to your script is relative to the current working directory, so you need to check whether that's what you think it is or not.

Comment: Is the script executable? It seems to work fine. But your scripts must be in the same directory as this program, and you need to launch the program from the same directory.

Comment: The script runs correctly, there is no problem with its path. The problem occurs on the last command of the script

Comment: Why do you have three functions with the same name? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get any error when selecting another script and pressing "Verify Certificate", nothing happens but I get no error.

Comment: The same name thing is just me being silly, but there is no problem there. Isn't the correct syntax for calling a script with an argument like that "./script_name.sh, argument" and in the script where you want to pass the argument you write '$1'

Comment: @user3120283 I'm afraid I don't know. I'm unable to replicate the error that you describe though.

Comment: What does `print(file)` give you? The absolute path?

Comment: @Idlehands Yes, the absolute path of the file i select with the browse file option

Comment: Does `python3 cert-issuer/cert-verifier/cert_verifier/verifier.py` actually run anything? is `cert-issuer` always a known path to `python3`? I feel like `python3` cannot locate `verifier.py` in your case.

Comment: Yes it does. I can run the same command in terminal `python3 cert-issuer/cert-verifier/cert_verifier/verifier.py +the absolute path of the file` and it works with no problem

Comment: `file` is assigned only locally in your `clicked` function, so in your other `clicked` function (please give all your functions different names) `file` is still `""`. You can use `var.get()` instead of `file`, since `var` stays the same object throughout.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Hmm you are correct. I printed `file` just before the script runs and i saw it was still `""`. You mean i change this `subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', file], shell=True)` to this `subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', var.get()], shell=True)`?

Edit: Can i run `print(var.get())` to see what's in it or must i run `print(var)`?

Comment: @fhdrsdg You were correct about `file` being assigned locally, so i've made a few changes to my code but it is still not working. I used `var.get()` like suggested and when i print it i have the correct absolute path i need. Then i called the script like this `subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', var.get()], shell=True)` But in the script when i `echo` the variable $1 i get nothing, meaning the path hasn't passed into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made it work, but i don't know why it does.
All i changed was instead of calling my script like this

`subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', var.get()], shell=True)`

i omitted the `shell=True` command and the argument passes correctly into the script.
So i called `subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', var.get()])` and it works just fine but i can't think why. Any explanation is much appreciated.